# What does this error mean? SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: mysql, oracle

I keep getting the error code 'ORA-02270' and no matter what I try, I can't seem to fix it. Below are my Create Table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
  studentID CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  studentName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  studentAddress VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  studentDOB DATE NOT NULL,
  studentGender CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK ((studentGender = 'F') OR (studentGender = 'M')),
  studentNationality VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  studentCourse VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  studentSemesterExcellent CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK ((studentSemesterExcellent = 'Y') OR (studentSemesterExcellent = 'N'))
);

CREATE TABLE leaseAgreement
(
  leaseNo CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,
  studentID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  leaseAccommodationType VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  leaseDuration NUMBER NOT NULL,
  leaseStartDate DATE NOT NULL,
  leaseEndDate DATE,
  studentSemesterExcellent CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK ((studentSemesterExcellent = 'Y') OR (studentSemesterExcellent = 'N')),
  FOREIGN KEY (studentID) REFERENCES student(studentID),
FOREIGN KEY (studentSemesterExcellent) REFERENCES student(studentSemesterExcellent)
);
```

Am I not allowed to have two foreign keys from the same table? Please can someone explain this error and point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: As the error message says, a foreign key must reference the primary key or a unique constraint in the parent table. `student.studentSemesterExcellent` is neither. It's not exactly clear what is the logic behind this strange foreign key on `studentSemesterExcellent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the answer from mustaccio is correct.
The column 'studentSemesterExcellent' in table 'student' is no key column. You can not reference it in a foreign key constraint.

And if you make it unique you can only have two rows in the student table, not what you are intending.

Second, you have tagged the question both with MySQL and Oracle. Choose one!

Third, you only need one FK if it is a not null column. Don't make it harder on yourself.

Fourth, if this is Oracle database, the advice is to only use varchar2() for string data. The char and varchar datatypes exist for compatibility reasons.